# My application is set in stopped =true state mode every 15 mim, or 24h, depends on some devices

Tags: android

According the documentation: Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but are not yet launched and when they are manually stopped by the user (in Manage Applications).
[see this link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html)

Well, In my case I made an app which first time ask user and password to login. Then goes background using `alarmmanager` so every trigger of the alarm awakes to perform some tasks with a service.

Then problem is, that in some models of android says:

```
User 0:  installed=true hidden=false stopped=true notLaunched=false enabled=0.
```

The problem in that is broadcast, gcm, etc stop working.
One could use `FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES`, but with gcm I don't see how.

In a galaxy s5(lolipop) after 24 more or less the app is stopped.
In another new mobile, wikio gelly(marshallow) its worse, some times every 15 minutes goes to stop mode.

The strange is the documentation says if the app is started only once and the user never stops the app. The app cannot enter in stopped mode = true.

**What can cause to stop the app?**

Any thought about it.

Thanks

Comment: at some point android system kill your app when it need more memory and you can not restrict system.

Answer (score 0):

The Android system can kill processes at any time, to reclaim memory for other apps/tasks. The 'Wikio Gelly' device probably has much less memory, or much more other processes, then the 'Galaxy S5', causing it to kill the app in such a short time.

See the Android Documentation on application lifecycles:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html

> the system may kill the process at any time to reclaim memory